# Does $T_3$ imply that the topological space is zero-dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

First, let me clear up my definitions:

1. A topological space is $T_3$ if, given any point $x$ and closed set $F$ in $X$ such that $x$ does not belong to $F$, they are separated by neighbourhoods.
2. A topological space is zero-dimensional if it has a basis from clopen sets.

Now, it is not hard to show that if a topological space is zero-dimensional, it is also $T_3$. However, I am wondering if the converse is also true; does every $T_3$ space have a basis from clopen sets? If that is the case, how can I prove it and if it isn't, can you provide me a counter-example and perhaps a slightly modified implication (perhaps with some additional requirement) that would hold?

Comment: All metric spaces are $T_3$ (actually $T_4$), so if this definition coincides with the usual definition for Euclidean space, this cannot possibly be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; $\mathbb{R}$ is a counterexample because its only clopen sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself. In fact, any connected metric space provides a counterexample.

Comment: Any idea how I could modify the reverse implication to be true?

Comment: @Matthew You cannot: zero-dimensional spaces are quite special. By far most regular spaces (metric spaces, topological groups, or more generally uniform spaces etc) are **not** zero-dimensional.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ok, thank you!

Comment: @Matthew Every zero-dimensional $T_0$-space is totally disconnected, so total disconnectedness is almost required (in your definition $T_3$ does not imply $T_0$, but we can think of the $T_0$-identification). There is a partial converse: Every totally disconnected locally compact Hausdorff space is zero-dimensional. This can't be much improved: A totally disconnected metric space need not be zero-dimensional. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan. This example, with $p$ removed, is totally disconnected but not zero-dimensional.